# Get / extract the date format currently used, from Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a function that gets/extracts the string literal "dd/mm/yyyy" or "mm/dd/yyyy" based on Django's localisation/internationalisation settings i.e. the default format that it is using, when displaying dates coming from a "models.DateField", in its template engine? Assuming that the localisation/internationalisation settings have been set.

**Update**

I tried to use SHORT_DATE_FORMAT, but it isn't set according to my localisation/internationalisation settings. I was expecting "d/m/Y". In "settings.py":

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

For example:

```
from django.conf import settings
print(settings.SHORT_DATE_FORMAT)
m/d/Y
print(settings.DATE_FORMAT)
N j, Y
```

Obviously this isn't the right approach.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Would you be more specific? Prepare some examples maybe?

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Template tags are typical python functions that are built-in inside Django.

So you can simply use the `date` template tag inside your view:

```py
In [1]: from django.template.defaultfilters import date

In [2]: someday = datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 16, 16, 9, 20, 585187, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [3]: date(someday)
Out[3]: 'March 16, 2019'

In [4]: date(someday, 'Y m D')
Out[4]: '2019 03 Sat'
```

Comment: That does not answer my question.